# Identity mask for numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I would have expected `True` to preserve a `ndarray` when used as a mask, however, it adds a dimension, just like `None`.

```
arr = np.arange(16).reshape(2, 4, 2)
np.all(arr[True] == arr)         # outputs: True
```

Close enough, however looking closer:

```
arr[True].shape                  # outputs: (1, 2, 4, 2)
arr[None].shape                  # outputs: (1, 2, 4, 2)
```

I found two ways to set an identity mask: using `slice(None)` or `Ellipsis`.

```
np.all(arr[slice(None)] == arr)  # outputs: True
arr[slice(None)].shape           # outputs: (2, 4, 2)

np.all(Ellipsis == arr)          # outputs: True
arr[Ellipsis].shape              # outputs: (2, 4, 2)
```

Nothing really surprising here as this is how slicing works in the first place. `slice(None)` is a tad ugly and `Ellipsis` seems a wee bit faster.
However, going through:

- [NumPy's doc on indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

I am not sure I fully understand this:

> Deprecated since version 1.15.0: In order to remain backward compatible with a common usage in Numeric, basic slicing is also initiated if the selection object is any non-ndarray and non-tuple sequence (such as a list) containing slice objects, the Ellipsis object, or the newaxis object, but not for integer arrays or other embedded sequences.

I understand that the best way to preserve an array is not to mask it, but say I really want to setup a default value for a mask... ;-)

***Question:*** Which is the preferred way to setup an identity mask ? And if I may, is `True` adding a dimension the intended behavior ?

Comment: The 2 that work are the same as `arr[:]` and `arr[...]`.  The return a view.  Boolean/mask indexing produces a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj if `arr[:]` returns a view, why is `q = arr[:]; q is arr` `False`?   I thought they should point to the same object in memory, genuinely curious

Comment: @anon01 they are two distinct objects pointing to the same memory. In other words they share data but not metadata.

Comment: @PaulPanzer ah cool, ty!  Can you point to a difference in the metadata?

Comment: @anon01 You can try looking at `arr.flags` vs `q.flags` If `arr` was a "clean" array they should have different `OWNDATA` bits. Also, their `.base` attributes could be different. But even if their metadata happen to have identical values they are not shared.

Comment: Your concept of a 'identity mask' is unclear (to me).

Comment: @hpaulj by identity mask, I mean a mask that preserves the array (that doesn't actually mask the array) like an identity transform would return the same value

Comment: `Ellipsis` is the most general way of indexing an array, and returning the same values.  It won't be the same array (in the `is` sense), but will be an identical `view`.  `slice(None)` is pretty general as well, but fails with 0d arrays ('scalar').

Comment: `arr[None]` is well documented as a synonymy for `arr[np.newaxis]`.  `arr[True]` appears to do the same, but `arr[False]` adds a size 0 dimension.  I don't think this is well documented, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree about `None` and `np.newaxis`, I was just surprised by the behavior of `True` and couldn't find a clear explanation of it in the docs

Comment: I'm not saying the  behavior is useful, but it is perfectly logical: The invariant is that if data are ND and mask is MD then each bit in the mask applies to an (N-M)D chunk of data. The resulting array has 1+N-M dimensions, because masking flattens, i.e. the masked dimensions are changed into a linear index. In your example True is a scalar aka 0D array. Output should therefore have 1+N-0 dimensions which is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

For a sample 2d array:

```
In [172]: x=np.array([[1,2],[4,3]])
In [173]: x.__array_interface__
Out[173]: 
{'data': (50806320, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

A view with ellipsis:

```
In [174]: x[...].__array_interface__
Out[174]: 
{'data': (50806320, False),          # same as for x
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

A view with an added dimension:

```
In [175]: x[None].__array_interface__
Out[175]: 
{'data': (50806320, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (1, 2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

A copy with an added dimension - note the change data address.  Advanced indexing.

```
In [176]: x[True].__array_interface__
Out[176]: 
{'data': (50796640, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (1, 2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

Another copy with a size 0 dimension.  It's reusing memory.

```
In [177]: x[False].__array_interface__
Out[177]: 
{'data': (50796640, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (0, 2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

The only applicable reference in the `indexing` page that I can find is:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#detailed-notes

> the nonzero equivalence for Boolean arrays does not hold for zero dimensional boolean arrays.

I wouldn't be surprised if this behavior was a left over from some past implementation.  Due a history of merging several numeric packages, there are some rough edges.  Some of those have been, or are in the process of, deprecation.

A scalar boolean index is a `zero dimensional boolean array`:

```
In [178]: np.array(True).shape
Out[178]: ()
```

We can add the new dimension else where:

```
In [181]: x[:,True].shape
Out[181]: (2, 1, 2)
In [183]: x[...,False].shape
Out[183]: (2, 2, 0)
```

Comment: Many thanks! So I can be confident that using `Ellipsis` (or the literal `...` which is the same) is the way to go in my case and won't get deprecated any time soon.

Comment: Interesting also to note that `True` is triggering advanced indexing, although that was understood from the docs, still nice to emphasize it here.

Answer (score 1):

You keep saying "mask", but it doesn't sound like you really want a masking operation at all, even an "identity" mask. A mask array would typically be a boolean array of the same shape as the original array, and indexing with the mask would produce a 1D array with items selected by the mask. Even an all-true mask would produce a flattened copy of the array it was applied to. It wouldn't be an identity operation. It's possible to do weirder things with masks, but not an identity operation.

If you want an indexer that outputs an equivalent array to the original, the typical, most general way to do that would be `...` - a literal ellipsis:

```
arr[...]
```

Unlike `:`, this also works for 0-dimensional arrays. Note that this produces a view, not a copy. There is no indexer that would produce a copy and work properly for all input dimensions.

---

`arr[True]` works like it does primarily out of a desire to have 0-dimensional arrays follow the same boolean indexing rules as positive-dimensional arrays. As mentioned above, if you index an n-dimensional array with an n-dimensional mask, the result is a 1-dimensional array. If you index a 0-dimensional array with a 0-dimensional mask, the result is again a 1-dimensional array:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: x = numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [3]: x[x % 2 == 0]
Out[3]: array([2, 4])

In [4]: y = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [5]: y[y % 2 == 0]
Out[5]: array([2, 4])

In [6]: z = numpy.array(5) # 0-dimensional!

In [7]: z[z % 2 == 0]
Out[7]: array([], dtype=int64)

In [8]: z[z % 2 == 1]
Out[8]: array([5])
```

Indexing a 0-dimensional array with a 0-dimensional mask increases the dimensionality by 1. Generalized to higher dimensions, indexing an n-dimensional array with a 0-dimensional mask produces an n+1-dimensional array. If the mask is True, the extra dimension has length 1; if the mask is False, the extra dimension has length 0, and the output has no elements. This generalized behavior is rarely useful, but it's what fits best with the (rarely useful) rules for applying a positive-dimension mask to an array with mismatching dimensions.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe it's more indexing than masking... and it's also true I haven't given much thoughts about the generalization of my problem. I was actually mostly working with 1D arrays, so indexing/masking 1D with 1D gives off... 1D again. That's where using `True` got me a 2D array and led to some unexpected behavior (although this was foreseeable, I didn't really understand this point by reading the docs).